# Access A Specific Item In DB in my for statement

Tags: python, django

I have a somewhat odd scenario. I am using a read only database that I have access through my property management software. They allow the user to define fields in there software. However they don't show up as specific fields in the database. The database has 2 tables related to them `propuserdefined` and `propuserdefinedvalues`. The `propuserdefined` contains all the info about the field(id, name, description) the `propuserdiefinedvalues` contains the values associated with the property. It has `propid`, `userdefinedid`, and `value`. My question is this, I need to access the value of `propuserdefinedvalues` where `propid` equals the `propid` in my for property in properties statement and the `userdefinedid` equals 49. How would I do this? Is it with a template tag?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Brandon

Here are my models.

```
class Propuserdefined(models.Model):
    userdefinedid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    type = models.IntegerField()
    userid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    combolist = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'propuserdefined'

class Propuserdefinedvalues(models.Model):
    userdefinedid = models.IntegerField()
    propid = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.TextField(blank=True)
    userid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'propuserdefinedvalues'

class Property(models.Model):
    propid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35L, blank=True)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=6L, blank=True)
    street1 = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2L, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=21L, blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=25L, blank=True)
    billname1 = models.CharField(max_length=35L, blank=True)
    billname2 = models.CharField(max_length=35L, blank=True)
    billstreet1 = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    billstreet2 = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    billcity = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    billstate = models.CharField(max_length=2L, blank=True)
    billzip = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    proptaxid = models.CharField(max_length=35L, blank=True)
    rentchargetype = models.CharField(max_length=20L, blank=True)
    lastpostdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    lastweeklypostdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=25L, blank=True)
    enablespeciallatecharge = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    fixedlatecharge = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    fixedlateamount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    fixedlaterentonly = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentlate = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentlateamount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentlatefullcharge = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentlaterentonly = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdaylate = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdaylateamount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdaylategrace = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdaylategracenum = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdatelatelimitamount = models.FloatField()
    perdaylategracenonretro = models.IntegerField()
    perdaylategraceexclweekends = models.IntegerField()
    perdaylategraceexclholidays = models.IntegerField()
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    userid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    logofile = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    merchantid = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    epaybankid = models.IntegerField()
    epaylimit = models.FloatField()
    epayenabled = models.IntegerField()
    achconveniencefeeenabled = models.IntegerField()
    ccconveniencefeeenabled = models.IntegerField()
    rwaachconvenciencefeeenabled = models.IntegerField()
    rwaccconveniencefeeenabled = models.IntegerField()
    epayislimited = models.IntegerField()
    epayusedefaults = models.IntegerField()
    achconveniencefee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    ccconveniencefee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    rwaachconveniencefee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    rwaccconveniencefee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    epaychargetype = models.IntegerField()
    epayamounttype = models.IntegerField()
    epaysetamount = models.FloatField()
    epaycustlimit = models.FloatField()
    sqft = models.IntegerField()
    lateminbalance = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    defaultbank = models.IntegerField()
    postday = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    iscommercial = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    assignedissueuserid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    altname = Propuserdefinedvalues.objects.filter(userdefinedid=49)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'property'
```

Comment: You're using django, according to the tags - do you have any models defined for this database? If so, and they're defined properly, then you should just be able to use the ORM.

Comment: I do have the models defined. I used the inspectdb to create them. The model "userdefinedvalues" contain values which are the "userdefinedfields" values. I need to access the field where the "userdefinedid" = 49 and the propid = the propid in the current loop of properties. I was hoping for soemthing like Property.Propertyuserdefinedvalues.49(Which is the foreignkey "userdefinedid").value

Comment: Can you post your models code? :)

Comment: Did you use `syncdb` or did oyu create the SQL by yourself?

Comment: I used inspectdb as this is a read only db that my property management software created.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to do this in a Django template. You should instead be using Python code, because Django templates are not designed for this.

The Django models for the table also won't provide the nicest interface for accessing these properties. Instead you should create some functions on top of them. Alternatively you could write raw SQL that do joins across the two tables.

Comment: Properly defined models with ForeignKeys set up should do this fine?

Answer (score 0):

Using your models as they are (there are no ForeignKeys defined, so you can't use the ORM to follow relationships), you can get the details like this (if I understood your question correctly):

```
property = Property.objects.get(name='my_property_name') # or however you get the property
prop_user_defined_values = Propuserdefinedvalues.objects.filter(propid=property.id, userdefinedid=49)
```

However, this could be shorted if you changed the order of your models, and some of your fields to type `ForiegnKey`:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    # ... rest truncated ...

class Propuserdefined(models.Model):
    # ... rest truncated ...

class Propuserdefinedvalues(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, db_column='propid')
    userdefined = models.ForeignKey(Propuserdefined, db_column='userdefinedid')
    # ... rest truncated ...
```

This would let you do something like:

```
Propuserdefinedvalues.objects.filter(userdefined__name='my_name', property__name='my_property')
# or:
my_property = Property.objects.get(name='my_property')
Propuserdefinedvalues.objects.filter(userdefined__userdefinedid=49, property=my_property)
```

I suggest you read about Django's models here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/ - they're quite easy to get right, even if you have pre-existing tables, as long as you know the relationships.

(Disclaimer: untested code! May be bugs ;))