# The Django Way To Write This Query?

Tags: python, django

I have a obscure database in Django. The database is read only and created by my property managements software. Basically in my view I need to write this query to get a specific record.

```
SELECT * FROM propuserdefinedvalues WHERE propid = propid and userdefinedid = 49
```

Is there a Django way to execute this instead of having raw SQL? I am looping through the "property" table. These records are in the "userdefinedcalues" table.

Here are my models.

```
class Property(models.Model):
    propid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35L, blank=True)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=6L, blank=True)
    street1 = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2L, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=21L, blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=25L, blank=True)
    billname1 = models.CharField(max_length=35L, blank=True)
    billname2 = models.CharField(max_length=35L, blank=True)
    billstreet1 = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    billstreet2 = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    billcity = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    billstate = models.CharField(max_length=2L, blank=True)
    billzip = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    proptaxid = models.CharField(max_length=35L, blank=True)
    rentchargetype = models.CharField(max_length=20L, blank=True)
    lastpostdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    lastweeklypostdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=25L, blank=True)
    enablespeciallatecharge = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    fixedlatecharge = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    fixedlateamount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    fixedlaterentonly = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentlate = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentlateamount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentlatefullcharge = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    percentlaterentonly = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdaylate = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdaylateamount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdaylategrace = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdaylategracenum = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perdatelatelimitamount = models.FloatField()
    perdaylategracenonretro = models.IntegerField()
    perdaylategraceexclweekends = models.IntegerField()
    perdaylategraceexclholidays = models.IntegerField()
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    userid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    logofile = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    merchantid = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    epaybankid = models.IntegerField()
    epaylimit = models.FloatField()
    epayenabled = models.IntegerField()
    achconveniencefeeenabled = models.IntegerField()
    ccconveniencefeeenabled = models.IntegerField()
    rwaachconvenciencefeeenabled = models.IntegerField()
    rwaccconveniencefeeenabled = models.IntegerField()
    epayislimited = models.IntegerField()
    epayusedefaults = models.IntegerField()
    achconveniencefee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    ccconveniencefee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    rwaachconveniencefee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    rwaccconveniencefee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    epaychargetype = models.IntegerField()
    epayamounttype = models.IntegerField()
    epaysetamount = models.FloatField()
    epaycustlimit = models.FloatField()
    sqft = models.IntegerField()
    lateminbalance = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    defaultbank = models.IntegerField()
    postday = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    iscommercial = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    assignedissueuserid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'property'

class Propuserdefined(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    userdefinedid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    type = models.IntegerField()
    userid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    combolist = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'propuserdefined'

class Propuserdefinedvalues(models.Model):
    userdefinedid = models.ForeignKey(Propuserdefined)
    propid = models.ForeignKey(Property)
    value = models.TextField(blank=True)
    userid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'propuserdefinedvalues'
```

Here is my view

```
def properties(request):
    properties = Property.objects.all().order_by('state')
    altname = SELECT * FROM propuserdefinedvalues WHERE propid = 73 and userdefinedid = 49
    return render_to_response('properties/index.html', {'properties':properties, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my template

```
{% for property in properties %}
{{ altname }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Brandon

Comment: Holy crap. Your first model is HUUUGE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access A Specific Item In DB in my for statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090820/access-a-specific-item-in-db-in-my-for-statement)

Comment: Are you actually trying to show the same altname for all properties in your template, or are you trying to get the altname that corresponds to each different propid as you loop through your properties?

Comment: Completely unrelated but irritating question: why are all your `max_length` values written as longs?  They're nowhere close to needing to be long, and `L` has been removed in Py3k

Comment: This appears to be an extremely simple query, the syntax for which is well covered in the tutorial and documentation. What, exactly, address you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Well this would be quite simple.

```py
var = 49
Property.objects.filter(propid=var).filter(userdefinedid=var)
```

That would be one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is guesswork as to exactly what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to get your template to look up a `Propuserdefinedvalues` with a predefined `userdefinedid` for each property in turn, the way to do this is either to define a custom template tag or to define a method on the `Property` class.  I tend towards the latter, at least when I don't need any fancy HTML.  You can also add attributes to your model instances in your view, but I find that less elegant.

```
class Property(models.Model):
    # huge list of fields

    def altname(self):
        return self.propuserdefinedvalues_set.filter(userdefinedid__name='altname')
```

Or whatever name is appropriate - avoid hardcoding the ID if at all possible.

Then in the template:

```
{% for property in properties %}
    {{ property.altname }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

In the view, using `select_related` in your queryset to preload the join will probably boost performance.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what i was looking for. I am getting an error of in which Django tries to select the ID.

Comment: (1054, "Unknown column 'propuserdefinedvalues.id' in 'field list'")

Comment: Is there a way to make Django ignore the id field?

Comment: Check your database schema - `Propuserdefinedvalues` doesn't have a primary key field explicitly stated, so Django tries to use the default `id` primary key.  If there's no such column on the table, that would explain the error.  Unfortunately, if there's no primary key at all on that table (such as if it's relying on a compound key of the `userdefinedid` and `propid`) the Django ORM doesn't really deal well with that situation.

Comment: It doesn't have a key. I set the key to the date created field. My new issue is it tells gives me this error:

Comment: (1054, "Unknown column 'propuserdefinedvalues.userdefinedid_id' in 'field list'")

Do you know how I could solve this one?

Comment: Django expects an integer primary key.  Without one, the ORM doesn't really work.  Do you have any ability to add a key to your database?

Comment: If you can't get your `propuserdefinedvalues` table to have an integer primary key, you can use an `extra` clause in your view's query set to do the join manually and get the value apparently present on the `Property` instances.  This is less elegant but it might be the best way possible. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra - you'd have a `select` argument with the sql for the join.